# How do css Infinity work?

Tags: html, css

here're plenty of different CSS shapes over at [CSS Tricks - Shapes of CSS](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) and I'm particularly puzzled with a Infinity:

[image]

```css
#infinity {
  position: relative;
  width: 212px;
  height: 100px;
}

#infinity:before,
#infinity:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 20px solid red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 50px;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 50px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#infinity:after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 0;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="infinity"></div>
```

How and why does it work?

Answer (score 3):

Two of these:

```css
#p1, #p2, #p3, #p4 {
  border: 20px solid red;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 60px;
}

#p2, #p3, #p4 {
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#p3, #p4 {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

#p4 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="p1"></div>
<div id="p2"></div>
<div id="p3"></div>
<div id="p4"></div>
```